# what can't be done with if else clause, and can be done with exception handling?

Tags: exception

what can't be done with if else clause, and can be done with exception handling ?

In other words where do we actually need to use exception handling and mere if else won't serve the purpose.

Is exception handling just a glorified way of showing errors ?

Comment: What can be done with an `if-else` that can't be done with a `goto`? Are `if-else` branches just a glorified way of writing a limited set of `goto`s?

Comment: @pst: Not so with exceptions.

Comment: @sharptooth I think my point was missed... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the earliest C++ implementations, exceptions were compiled into equivalent if/else constructs, more or less.  And they were slow as molasses, to the point where you can still find programming guides that recommend against exceptions on the grounds that "they are slow".

So it is not a question of "can" or "cannot".  It is a question of readability and performance.

Littering every line of your code with error checks makes it harder for a human to follow the non-exceptional (i.e. common) case.  And as every good programmer knows, the primary audience for your code is human readers.

As for performance, if/else is *slower* than a modern exception implementation.  Modern implementations incur literally zero overhead except when an exception is actually thrown.  If your exceptions truly represent "exceptional" cases, this can be a significant performance difference.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages (for example C++) don't allow return values in certain cases. For example, in C++ constructors don't have return values (even `void`), so the only way to signal an error in a constructor is to throw an exception.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's impossible to handle it without exceptions, you could create an object with an `isValid` flag in a field for example.

Comment: @trutheality: Who would have to check that flag?

Comment: everyone who tries to use the object of course. I didn't say it's pretty, just that it's not impossible.

Comment: Avoid both if you can. Avoid exceptions unless exceptional. Also do not want to check a status if can avoid.  Constructors should return a "valid" instance, my rule is an object with a valid graph of associations.  I avoid much else in a constructor, I think some things should essentially never fail.   My constructors require valid inputs, period.  If something requires some further initialization/validation, a return value is still only useful if the user can supply some fix.  So an explicit initialization function call is appropriate - the user must be prepared to participate anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Look, there isn't anything you can do with exceptions you can't do with hand-coded 8086 assembler. (Turing complete!) Except that hand-coded assembler isn't a very good tool for a 100K lines-of-code project unless you are the best coder in the Milky Way, if then. Experience shows a number of situations where the idiom of exception handling yields the most robust code written by ordinary humans. Sharptooth's example of ctors is good. So are errors that need to propagate up the call stack. **Edit:** And how many people actually check that `malloc` didn't fail every single time? Better to throw an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are just what they are named for: Exceptional events or situations which break the current flow.

You should use exceptions to indicate that something nasty and very exceptional has happened. Let's say you have a class which reads your configuration file. Exceptional situations could be:

- The file cannot be found.
- The file exists, but cannot be read.
- The file was deleted in the middle of
  a read operation.

You **could** handle all of these with if-else blocks but it is much simpler to do with exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you *can* write code that does not use exceptions. However, if you do, you would have make sure that any function that could issue an error is handled properly.

For me, the biggest advantage of having exceptions is that I can write straight code that simply assumes that all functions succeeds, knowing that upper layers will take care of reporting errors.

Concretely, take the following fictitious function to work with text in an editor:

```
do-stuff:
    backward-line 10
    x = point
    search-for "FOO"
    return buffer-substring x point
```

Both "backward-line" and "search-for" could fail. If I would have to handle errors myself, I would have to check them. In addition, I would have to invent a side-channel to report to my caller that an error occurred. As I said, it can be done, but it would be a lot messier.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a following real-life example. You have a complex recursive function and need to get out of all the calls currently in progress on some condition.

```
void complexFunction()
{
   //do stuff, then
   if( timeToBailOut() ) {
      // what? how would you get out of all instances at once?
   }       
}
```

You would need to write those `if` statements very carefully, perhaps introduce a special return value, check for that value at all times, that would complicate you code greatly. You can easily achieve that behavior with exceptions.

```
if( timeToBailOut() ) {
    throw BailOutException();
}
```

Comment: Arguably, it could be just as cleanly written returning `Either(Result,Error)`. I generally cry when I run into this sort of expected "backout" method.

Comment: @pst: What would `Either()` do?

Comment: @sharptooth It can be thought of as a Tuple with two mutually-exclusive elements where *one and only one* of the items can be set (or accessed). *Either* the first value -- often called Left -- can be set or the second value -- often called Right -- can be set. In the above comment I was meaning the Left type to be Result and the Right type to be Error. E.g. A normal return would be `Left(some_result)` and the "error" return would be `Right(some_error)` which would both be unified under `Either(Result,Error)`. Normally pattern matching is used to decompose to the Left or Right values.

Comment: @pst: Okay, but the caller would have to check that value and react accordingly and this would be extra code. With exceptions it's just a `catch` at the top level.

Comment: @sharptooth The argument was that `BailOutException` is an abuse -- it is an *expected* condition and therefore can be codified -- and not something like an IO or memory exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that can be done with exception handling that can't be done without it, however, some situations would be a pain without exception handling.

Example: `a()` calls `b()` and `b()` calls `c()`. An error might occur in `c()` that has to be handled in `a()`. Without exception handling you would have to deal with it by using sentinel return values in `b()` and `c()`, and extra checking code in `b()`. You can imagine how much more code you would need to write if the error has to be passed through more levels from what caused it to what needs to handle it.

This is a short version of my answer to a [different question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81567/is-exception-handling-in-php-greatly-overrated/81584#81584) that was asked here earlier and migrated.